# Can't see Android Studio but it is installed

Tags: android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating fresh project in `ionic` that uses `cordova`. When I run `ionic cordova run android` I'm getting error that I have to install Android Studio. But I have it installed - using JetBrains Toolbox.

Here is my error:
[image]

When I use `ionic` with `capacitor` everything is working.

Comment: Its asking for gradle and not android. U need to install gradle ...

Comment: Isn't it installed with Android Studio?

Comment: Nope, usually when creating a new project in android studio and building it for first time, it automatically downloads the gradle files on the system..

Comment: Download gradle (https://gradle.org/install/) and set path in `set path in environment variable`